# Using Modal from headless ui in vue3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, headless-ui

I want to use **headless ui modal** in vue3 but the problem is I don't understand how I can toggle the modal from parent (App.vue) if the modal is a component.

I tried to pass a prop in the Modal.vue but it's not working, my strategy was to use a modalActive prop and watch it and call appropriate function to toggle the modal, but it's simply not working.

The example in headless UI uses a button but that's inside the component it self so obviously it can access functions of that component without problem.

My code:

**App.vue**

```
<template>
  <Modal>
    <template v-slot:default>
      <LoginForm />
    </template>
  </Modal>
</template>


<script setup lang="ts">

import Modal from './components/Modal.vue';
import LoginForm from './components/LoginForm.vue';
import { ref } from 'vue';

</script>
```

**Modal.vue**

```
<template>
    <TransitionRoot appear :show="isOpen" as="template">
        <Dialog as="div" @close="closeModal">
            <div class="fixed inset-0 z-10 overflow-y-auto">
                <div class="min-h-screen px-4 text-center">
                    <TransitionChild
                        as="template"
                        enter="duration-300 ease-out"
                        enter-from="opacity-0"
                        enter-to="opacity-100"
                        leave="duration-200 ease-in"
                        leave-from="opacity-100"
                        leave-to="opacity-0"
                    >
                        <DialogOverlay class="fixed inset-0" />
                    </TransitionChild>
                    <span class="inline-block h-screen align-middle" aria-hidden="true">&#8203;</span>
                    <TransitionChild
                        as="template"
                        enter="duration-300 ease-out"
                        enter-from="opacity-0 scale-95"
                        enter-to="opacity-100 scale-100"
                        leave="duration-200 ease-in"
                        leave-from="opacity-100 scale-100"
                        leave-to="opacity-0 scale-95"
                    >
                        <div
                            class="inline-block w-full max-w-md p-6 my-8 overflow-hidden text-left align-middle transition-all transform bg-white shadow-xl rounded-2xl"
                        >
                            <slot></slot> <!-- slot for forms -->
                        </div>
                    </TransitionChild>
                </div>
            </div>
        </Dialog>
    </TransitionRoot>
</template>

<script setup lang="ts">
import { ref, watch } from 'vue'
import {
    TransitionRoot,
    TransitionChild,
    Dialog,
    DialogOverlay,
    DialogTitle,
} from '@headlessui/vue'

const isOpen = ref(true)


function closeModal() {
    isOpen.value = false

}
function openModal() {
    isOpen.value = true
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 9):

You should use [`defineExpose`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#sfc-script-setup) together with `$refs`.

```
<script setup>
import { ref, watch, defineExpose } from 'vue'

...      

const closeModal =  function() {
    isOpen.value = false
}
const openModal = function() {
    isOpen.value = true
}
  
defineExpose({
  openModal,
  closeModal
})
  
</script>
```

Template reference to your component:

```
  <Modal ref="modal">
```

And the method `openModal` in the Vue App:

```
components: {
      Modal
    },
    methods: {
      openModal() {
        this.$refs.modal.openModal();
      }
    }
```

Here is a working version: [Vue SFC Playground](https://sfc.vuejs.org/#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)

Here are the important parts of Vue 3 Documentation to understand the solution:

- [Template Refs](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/composition-api-template-refs.html#template-refs)
- [SFC `<script setup>`](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/sfc-script-setup.html#sfc-script-setup)

Comment: Excellent, didn't realise defineExpose was a thing when transitioning from Vue2 to Vue3. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

[Tolbxela's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69919635/2227743) works great, but if you're using the composition api, the final part of the answer will look a little different.

```js
const modal = ref(null)
//the variable name (modal) needs to match the template ref name 
//given in the second step of Tolbxela's answer

const openModal = () => {
    modal.value.openModal()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for these answers guys - I was having the same issue (not a Vue composition guy yet, as just coming from Vue 2.x).

If anyone's interested, I've made my dialog only close when clicking the "close" button on the dialog itself (not esc key or clicking outside of the dialog). It makes the Modal actually 'modal'.

```
<script setup>
  import { ref, watch, onMounted, onUnmounted } from 'vue'
  import {
    TransitionRoot,
    TransitionChild,
    Dialog,
    DialogPanel,
    DialogTitle,
  } from '@headlessui/vue'

  const isOpen = ref(false)
  
  function openModal(myEvent) {
    isOpen.value = true
  }

  function closeModal(ev) {
    if (typeof ev.target === 'undefined') return
    if (ev.target.id !== 'closeDialogBtn') return   // Give the 'close' button an id.
    isOpen.value = false
  }

  onMounted(() => {
    // block esc key from closing dialog.
    document.addEventListener('keydown', makeDialogModal)
  })

  onUnmounted(() => {
    // block esc key from closing dialog.
    document.removeEventListener('keydown', makeDialogModal)
  })

  function makeDialogModal(e) {
    if (e.key === 'Escape' || e.keyCode === 27) { // e.keyCode === 27 used for legacy
          console.log('Escape key pressed')
          e.stopPropagation()
          return
      }
  }

  defineExpose({
    openModal,
    closeModal
  })


</script>
```